# tmux: will it support regex for the session name when we want to capture pane output

Tags: tmux

I have a situation where in my script i keep appending some text to the original session name

EG: First time when i create a new session

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S_%N`
tmux new-session -d -s "$today" zsh /home/path/to/script.sh "with_params"
```

IN my script.sh based on some condition i want add some text infront of the session name:

```
session_name=`tmux display-message -p "#S"`  #this gets the session name in which the script is running
tmux rename-session -t ${session_name} ABC_${session_name}
```

....after some code again i rename it

```
session_name=`tmux display-message -p "#S"`  #this gets the session name in which the script is running
tmux rename-session -t ${session_name} XYZ_${session_name}
```

So whats happening here is

```
my original session name is "2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687"
Its gets renamed to XYZ_2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687 or ABC_2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687 or KLM_2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687 etc based on certain conditions.
```

Now i want to capture the last five lines output of this session. I Know it has only one window and only one pane

```
$ tmux capture-pane -p -S- -E- -e -t *2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687* |sed '/^$/d'|tail -5
zsh: no matches found: *2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687*
```

So how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `*`s if you want them to be processed by tmux rather than the shell. Either `\*` or put the whole thing in `'`s.

Comment: `tmux capture-pane -p -S- -E- -e -t \*2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687 |sed '/^$/d'|tail -5` I tires it says `can't find pane *2020-04-10-11_52_01_953906687`

Comment: Add a `:` at the end so tmux knows you want a session.

Comment: `tmux capture-pane -p -S- -E- -e -t \*2020-04-10-13_34_35_533928857: |sed '/^$/d'|tail -5` . @Nicholas, Thanks this worked